# Grails 3: find domains that were added to another one in many-to-many relationship (No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: grails

I'm a Grails newbie and I found the following obstacle:

I have 2 domains: Course and Student, they have a many-to-many relationship (a Course can have several students, a student can enroll in several courses) and the student belongs to the course.

So, when I add a student to a course, I want to be able to find what Courses have added a specific student.

I tried to use:

def s = Student.get(id)

def c = Course.findAllByStudents(s)

But grails keeps telling me "No value specified for parameter 1".

Can you guys throw some light into this?

Comment: This is not enough information. Give full stacktrace and code of your domain classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Course.findAllByStudents` expects as parameter `Set` of Students but you are supplying it with single `instance` of Student, that's why you are getting `"No value specified for parameter 1"`.

To find in what Courses is Student. If you created domain classes like this:

```
class Course {
    //some Course attributes
    static hasMany = [students: Student] 
}

class Student {
     //some Student attributes
     static hasMany = [courses: Course]
     static belongsTo = Course
}
```

then you can simply use `s.courses`.

If you are not two-way mapping that relationship. You can create criteria like this:

```
Course.withCriteria {
    createAlias 'students', 's'
    eq 's.elements', s
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now. Thank you so so much.